# req.body comes empty in delete operation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a problem in backend side:

```
recordRoutes.route("/:id").delete((req, res) => {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb("employees");
  var myquery = {
    id: req.body.id
  };
  db_connect.collection("records").deleteOne(myquery, function (err, obj) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 document deleted", req.body.id);
  });
});
```

since it displays "1 document deleted undefined" in console.

req.body comes empty.

But I dont have any problem with post operation.

Comment: Looking at the code, I see deleteRecord passing record_id, not record._id.

Comment: It was record._id but still gave me undefined value not the correct id

Comment: Try printing the contents of req.body, Maybe a different name?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are getting the id from the query param `/:id`, if you are passing it as a query param you won't be able to get it from `req.body`.

Try this instead:

```
var myquery = {
    id: req.params.id
}
```